# On the 2nd iteration of loop Python throws error "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'to_thread' was never awaited"

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have one "parent" sync function and one "child" sync function. I want to run few "child" functions as a result I convert them to coroutine. Child functions/coroutines I run inside loop - for some reason the 1st loop returns result, but the 2nd one throws `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'to_thread' was never awaited`

Minimal code:

```
import asyncio


def some_func(number):
    print('task number:', number)
    return number


def start():
    for r in range(2):
        print('r:', r)

        tasks = []

        for i in range(5):
            tasks.append(asyncio.to_thread(some_func, i))

        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        results = loop.run_until_complete(responses)
        loop.close()

        print('results:', results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Result:

```
r: 0
task number: 0
task number: 1
task number: 2
task number: 3
task number: 4
results: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
r: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/antonio/www/tourbase/booking-system/back-end/arctic_reservations/src/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    start()
  File "/media/antonio/www/tourbase/booking-system/back-end/arctic_reservations/src/test.py", line 18, in start
    responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 827, in gather
    fut = _ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 680, in _ensure_future
    return loop.create_task(coro_or_future)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 434, in create_task
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'to_thread' was never awaited
```

If I put `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` and `loop.close()` outside of for loop, everything is ok.

Could anybody explain why it happens? As I understand, the 2nd loop should create a new event loop.

Python v3.11.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the first iteration, you closed the event loop.

> As I understand, the 2nd loop should create a new event loop.

No, [`get_event_loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) returns the existing event loop. When you try to submit new tasks to it in the second iteration, it tells you that you cannot do this because it is already closed.

The function that always creates a new event loop is called [`new_event_loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.new_event_loop).

But instead of trying to manage multiple event loops yourself by  `asyncio.get_event_loop` and `loop.run_until_completed` and `loop.close`, you can simply use a single event loop which [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run) handles for you automatically (`start` needs to become a coroutine):

```
import asyncio


def some_func(number):
    print('task number:', number)
    return number


async def start():
    for r in range(2):
        print('r:', r)

        tasks = []

        for i in range(5):
            tasks.append(asyncio.to_thread(some_func, i))

        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        print('results:', results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())
```

Comment: The 1st loop closes the 1st event loop, but the 2nd loop creates a new event loop -> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() and python throws an error. Why created 2nd even loop does not work? :)

Comment: "No, get_event_loop returns the existing event loop." - do you mean that one instance of Python has just one event loop? If "yes", it explain this problem. I thought that calling "asyncio.get_event_loop()" we create as many event loops as we need. Thank you!

Comment: There can be more than one event loop, but managing them correctly can become complicated quickly.